Custom MIME Type Iconpack (glTF)
If one was to build or edit an icon pack for GNOME, and one wanted to add icons for filetypes that would be recognized, you would have to put your .svg in a folder where the MIME types are stored.  But what about filetypes whose MIME you don't know?
For example, I want to add a newly designed icon for the glTF file (*.gltf) and the icons in the MIME type folder are named along the patter of application-x-*.svg or text-*.svg. I've tried several combinations for .gltf and cannot get the desktop to recognize it when I load the icon pack.
This should be easy to figure out, and I've looked up the file's registered MIME type (model/gltf+json) but not sure how to name a file after that since /s aren't allowed in filenames.
